# Angular 4: How to watch an object for changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**ETA: I know that there are various ways to watch my *form* for changes. That is not what I am trying to do. As the title says, I am asking how to watch for changes to an *object*. The app shown below is for illustration purposes only. Please answer the question that I have asked. Thanks!**

I have this simple app:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Customer {
    firstName: string;
    favoriteColor: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="customer">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="customer.firstName">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="customer.favoriteColor">
        </div>
        `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private customer: Customer;

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.customer = new Customer();

        // TODO: how can I register a callback that will run whenever
        // any property of this.customer has been changed?

    }

}
```

Note the TODO. I need to register a callback that will run whenever any property of  `this.customer` has been changed.

**I cannot use ngChange on the inputs. I need to subscribe directly to changes on the model.** The reasons pertain to my use case, and aren't worth going into here. Just trust me that this isn't an option.

Is this possible? I've done a lot of Googling, but I've come up dry.

Comment: Use a reactive form, and use the valueChanges observable exposed by the FormGroup.

Comment: Are these inputs in any kind of form? If they aren't they should be. If they are subscribe to the form's changes.

Comment: The state of the form and the state of the object are identical. You can't listen to changes on an object. But since each time the form changes, the model also changes, listening to changes on the form is basically equivalent to listening to changes on the object.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a simple getter/setter to every Customer object? I'm honestly not even sure if that's possible, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: have you perhaps figured this out yet? it's amazing that there is no SIMPLE way to do it.. and it's sort of a common building block in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, no – I gave up on the approach.

Answer (score 50):

Angular usually uses injected into constructor [KeyValueDiffers](https://angular.io/api/core/KeyValueDiffers) class.

For your case it could look like:

```typescript
import { KeyValueChanges, KeyValueDiffer, KeyValueDiffers } from '@angular/core';

export class Customer {
  firstName: string;
  favoriteColor: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `./app.component.html`
})
export class AppComponent {
  private customerDiffer: KeyValueDiffer<string, any>;
  private customer: Customer;

  constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customer = new Customer();
    this.customerDiffer = this.differs.find(this.customer).create();
  }

  customerChanged(changes: KeyValueChanges<string, any>) {
    console.log('changes');
    /* If you want to see details then use
      changes.forEachRemovedItem((record) => ...);
      changes.forEachAddedItem((record) => ...);
      changes.forEachChangedItem((record) => ...);
    */
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
      const changes = this.customerDiffer.diff(this.customer);
      if (changes) {
        this.customerChanged(changes);
      }
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgcles?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

One more option is using setter on properties that you want to check.

See also

- http://blog.mgechev.com/2017/11/14/angular-iterablediffer-keyvaluediffer-custom-differ-track-by-fn-performance/

Comment: this is the only approach I found that worked, but IMHO this is not *clean* or *simple* by any means and it sucks that we're not provided with a better way to handle an "object property changed, let me know" situation than having to use a 10-line pattern to accomplish it.

Comment: I had to use a combination of this answer and @alexKhymenko's answer below, in order to make sure my code noticed all changes.

Comment: you saved my... month...

Comment: Would be great if there was a little more detail/ further reading on using a custom setter here.

Comment: I have multiple child components that need to be fed a "settings" dict. Is there a way to abstract all this differ code to a service? Its a pain to copy paste all this code in so many places..

Answer (score 37):

> I need to subscribe directly to changes on the model.

Then you need to listen to model changes with `ngModelChange`

**Template:**

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)" [ngModel]="customer.firstName">
```

**Class**:

```
doSomething(event) {
  console.log(event); // logs model value
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ademju?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 11):

You can't watch changes in an object. **Its not angular 1** there are no watchers here. Another solution will be via observables.

use form

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="customer.firstName">
  <input type="text" name="favoriteColor" [(ngModel)]="customer.favoriteColor">
</form>
```

in code

```
@ViewChild('f') f;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.f.form.valueChanges.subscribe((change) => {
   console.log(change)
  })
}
```

Comment: Angular4 automatically sets **novalidate** to ngForms.

Comment: :-) taking directly from their documentation https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#form

Comment: @Mihailo but deleted :-) should open pull request on documentation

Comment: I had to use `setTimeout()` to ensure that the model was updated with the new value(s) before I could act on the change..

Answer (score 6):

You could use custom setters to trigger your callback:

```
class Customer {
  private _firstName: string
  get firstName(): string {
    return this._firstName
  }
  set firstName(firstName: string) {
    this.valueChanged(this._firstName, firstName)
    this._firstName = firstName
  }

  private _lastName: string
  get lastName(): string {
    return this._lastName
  }
  set lastName(lastName: string) {
    this.valueChanged(this._lastName, lastName)
    this._lastName = lastName
  }

  valueChanged: (oldVal, newVal) => void

  constructor (valueChanged?: (oldVal, newVal) => void) {
    // return an empty function if no callback was provided in case you don't need
    // one or want to assign it later
    this.valueChanged = valueChanged || (() => {})
  }
}
```

Then just assign the callback when you create the object:

```
this.customer = new Customer((oldVal, newVal) => console.log(oldVal, newVal))

// or

this.customer = new Customer()
this.customer.valueChanged = (oldVal, newVal) => console.log(oldVal, newVal)
```

Comment: [this is the stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eskpoz?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 4):

visit https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-observe. it bases on rxjs and proxy.

```
import { observe } from "rxjs-observe";

const instance = { name: "Alice" };
const { observables, proxy } = observe(instance);
observables.name.subscribe(value => console.log(name));
proxy.name = "Bob";
```

Answer (score 1):

We are tasked with converting an Angular 1.x app to Angular 9.  It's an application with ESRI maps, so we have some neat tools that the ESRI framework brought to the table.  ESRI has watchUtils that do a whole lot more than just watch for changes.

But I missed Angular 1's simple $watch.  Besides, we create Entities and Models in our application, and we may need to observe these from time to time.

I created an abstract class called MappedPropertyClass.  It uses a Map<string, any> to map class properties, which allows me to easily implement toJSON and other utility functions.

The other Map this class has is _propertyChangeMap: Map<string, EventEmitter<{newvalue,oldvalue}>;

We also have a function called...    $watch, which takes a string and a callback function.

This class can be extended by Entities as well as components or services

I'm happy to share,  the caveat is your properties must look like this:

```
public get foo(): string {
    return this._get("foo");
}  
public set foo(value:string) {
    this._set("foo", value);
}


--------------------------------------------------------------------
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class MappedPropertyClass {
    private _properties: Map<string, any>;
    private _propertyChangeMap: Map<string, EventEmitter<{ newvalue, oldvalue }>>;

    protected _set(propertyName: string, propertyValue: any) {
        let oldValue = this._get(propertyName);
        this._properties.set(propertyName, propertyValue);
        this.getPropertyChangeEmitter(propertyName).emit({ newvalue: 
    propertyValue, oldvalue: oldValue });
    }

    protected _get(propertyName: string): any {
        if (!this._properties.has(propertyName)) {
            this._properties.set(propertyName, undefined);
        } 
        return this._properties.get(propertyName);
    }

    protected get properties(): Map<string, any> {
        var props = new Map<string, any>();
        for (let key of this._properties.keys()) {
            props.set(key, this._properties.get(key));
        }

        return props;
    }

    protected constructor() {
        this._properties = new Map<string, any>();
        this._propertyChangeMap = new Map<string, EventEmitter<{ newvalue: any, 
        oldvalue: any }>>();
    }

    private getPropertyChangeEmitter(propertyName: string): EventEmitter<{ 
                         newvalue, oldvalue }> {
        if (!this._propertyChangeMap.has(propertyName)) {
            this._propertyChangeMap.set(propertyName, new EventEmitter<{ newvalue, 
            oldvalue }>());
        }
        return this._propertyChangeMap.get(propertyName);
    }

    public $watch(propertyName: string, callback: (newvalue, oldvalue) => void): 
    any {
        return this.getPropertyChangeEmitter(propertyName).subscribe((results) => 
        {
            callback(results.newvalue, results.oldvalue);
        });
    }
}
```